# Using react-router-dom Link inside of a React Component Library not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-router-dom

I am building a React TypeScript application, and as part of it, I have split the components into a React component library. I want to create a button component that uses the `<Link>` component from `react-router-dom`, however, this is the error I receive:

> Cannot destructure property 'basename' of '(0 ,
> react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)(...)' as it is null.

**Scenario**

- `button.tsx` file is located in`ui-kit`, which is the component library.
- `Navbar.tsx` component is located within `frontend` folder, which is the main application.

I have used `npm link ui-kit` to link them together, and I have used `npm link ../frontend/node_modules/react` to link the react from the main application to the ui-kit so i don't use two reacts.

button.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

interface ButtonProps {
  className: string;
  link?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Link className={props.className} to={props.link || ''}>
      {props.children}
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

I then run `npm run build` which will compile the component library together and automatically send the dist/ to the main application. When it gets there, the above error appears.

```
{
  "name": "component-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.modern.js",
  "source": "src/index.tsx",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run compile-scss && npm run compile-ts",
    "compile-scss": "sass scss/main.scss dist/styles.css",
    "compile-ts": "microbundle-crl --no-compress --format modern,cjs",
    "start": "microbundle-crl watch --no-compress --format modern,cjs",
    "prepare": "run-s build",
    "test": "run-s test:unit test:lint test:build",
    "test:build": "run-s build",
    "test:lint": "eslint .",
    "test:unit": "cross-env CI=1 react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "test:watch": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "predeploy": "cd example && npm install && npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d example/build"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.51",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.22",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^9.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "microbundle-crl": "^0.13.10",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^6.20.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you rending your `Button` component within a router component? The router provides the routing context.

Comment: @DrewReese yes it is being rendered in a router component. Using <Link> inside the main application works fine, just not when passed from the component library.

Comment: I see. You may need to specify `react-router-dom` as a peer dependency in your component library/repo, or similar to what you might have done for `react` so there aren't multiple "instances". Can you [edit] to include the package.json file of your component library/repo?

Comment: Of course, I've added the package.json file and i have also run `npm link ../frontend/node_modules/react-router-dom` however that doesn't get put into the peerdependencies section for some reason.

Comment: No, I wouldn't expect it to do that. Adding `react-router-dom` as a peer dependency is done manually. `react-router-dom` also re-exports ***all*** of `react-router`, so I don't believe it needs to be listed at all as a project dependency.

Comment: I ended up just passing Link as a prop into the component and that worked fine.